# LESS variable passed via environment variable

Tags: javascript, webpack, less

I would like to have a variable in [LESS](http://lesscss.org) based on an environment variable:

```
@asset-path: process.env.IN_SHELL ? '/path/1/' : '/path/2/'
```

Since my asset path is different depending on the context the app is loaded in.

I'm using webpack (v4) with latest less, less-loader, style-loader, and postcss-loader (for vendor prefixing). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use javascript functions in LESS. The logic needs to be in your webpack config.
I think I would use [string-replace-loader](https://github.com/Va1/string-replace-loader) as the first loader for the LESS files and replace a placeholder for the correct path.

Something like this:

```
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        'postcss-loader',
        'less-loader',
        {
            loader: 'string-replace-loader',
            options: {
                search: 'PATH-PLACEHOLDER',
                replace: process.env.IN_SHELL ? '/path/1/' : '/path/2/',
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

Comment: That's a clever idea thanks, I'm going to mark it as correct and maybe try it someday. For now I've just stuck with image sources so far and passing the path in JS. I've imported JS config files into postcss before but had a feeling LESS was... less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modifyVars feature in LessLoader

```
modifyVars : { 'asset-path': process.env.IN_SHELL ? '/path/1/' : '/path/2/'}
```